# Cntlm deny all but 1 IP (windows)

Tags: windows, proxy, acl, windows-firewall

I have a windows cntlm proxy set up and working.

Now I would like to open it as gateway but limit the IPs that can call it. This means deny all except one ip address.

Currently i tried this and similar configs in cntlm.ini:

> Allow     10.10.10.1/32
>
> Deny        0/0

But blocks everything.

Any idea how to do it? I was unsuccessful searching the web.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to get it working with this setup.

```
# Enable to allow access from other computers
#
Gateway yes

# Useful in Gateway mode to allow/restrict certain IPs
# Specifiy individual IPs or subnets one rule per line.
#
Allow       10.10.10.1     # my computer ip
Allow       127.0.0.1
Allow       10.0.75.0/24   # docker interfaces range
Deny        0/0            # deny everyone else
```

Comment: In Linux environment, using `/etc/cntlm.conf`, it seems that the Allow/Deny list only works if it is line after sequential line; I find that if I add a comments line (`#`) between entries, it will not work properly. I see in your example you put the comments after each statement--so that is good to know--many thanks for showing this example.